# React/Service worker unsure of reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, glob, service-worker

I am trying to set up a service worker for my react app using `sw-precache` ( https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache ) and am looking at some examples for reference. I of what a certain line of code means, and can't seem to find what it means googling. So looking at `/!(*map*)`  in the context of -

```
module.exports = {
  stripPrefix: 'build/',
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'build/*.html',
    'build/manifest.json',
    'build/static/**/!(*map*)' <-- here
  ],
  dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
  swFilePath: 'build/service-worker.js'
};
```

I am not sure what that does/means and am wondering if anyone could provide some clarity, I am not able to find a good reference googling. I am looking at https://github.com/jeffposnick/create-react-pwa/blob/c-r-pwa-0.6.0/sw-precache-config.js for reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that map files won't be included. So your map files for CSS and JS.

But actually it wouldn't include *anything* with the characters `map` in the filename or directory name.

Comment: It's called a glob pattern. Basically regex for selecting a range of files. Here's a good quick resource: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer

Comment: Thanks again! That is much easier to google than 'map glob' :)